# Pass prompt values in advance while running a python script

Tags: python

There is a python script already created by other team member, while running the script it asks for some prompts for example user and password. As initially it was created assuming that every one will manually run the script by supplying prompt values.
Now I am trying to automatically run the script using CRON job, but I am not sure how to pass the prompt values in advance while running the script.

Here is a simple prompt present in the script

```
pwd = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter your password for user {}:
 ".format(user))
```

Thanks

Comment: It is pretty hard to answer this without seeing any code. Are the prompts done by `input`s?

Comment: here is a simple prompt in the script pwd = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter your password for user {}: ".format(user))

Comment: What is inside the `getpass` function in the `getpass` module?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, want the to enter the values like `python main.py value1 value2 value3` into the command line. If so then you can use the sys module of python. In your python script add the following code

```
import sys
val1 = sys.argv[1]
val2 = sys.argv[2]
val3 = sys.argv[3]
```

Here sys.argv is a list with all elements typed after `python` in the command line.
Its 0th element is the script name i.e. `main.py` in this case. Other elements are corresponding arguments you have passed like value1, value2 etc.
You can schedule a CRON job to type the command in command line with username and password as cmdline arguments

Comment: Actually i dont want to edit the existing script, just trying to figure out a way to run script by passing Prompts values in advance.

Comment: also use argparse to read arguments for your scripts. it's python's stdlib, simple, and really powerfull

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like: `echo my_password | python the_python_script.py`

if you need many input : `{ echo input1; echo input2; } | python the_python_script.py`

but you should edit the script as others have suggested